# Adding pandas dataframe iteratively in a memory efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, dataframe

I am trying to iteratively add some pandas dataframe that I read from a set of csv files, and after the 16th file or so I get a memory error. The new files are pandas of around 300k rows.

Is there a way to do this in the hard drive (for example with hdf5) or in a more memory efficient way?

See code below. Note that sum_of_all_files start as an empty dataframe.

```
sum_of_all_files = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in list_of_files:
    file_df=pd.read_csv(file_name,index_col=0,header=None).dropna()
    sum_of_all_files=sum_of_all_files.add(file_df,fill_value=0, axis='index')
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I want to add by index, i.e. if two rows have the same index, add them. I have corrected the code above by adding " axis='index' " in the last line.

Comment: what is your goal to load everything into one DF or to process it on the fly and write back to disk?

Comment: @MaxU The goal is to have a table with the content of all the csv files added by keys. It can be in the disk or in memory...

Comment: How many columns have csvs?

Comment: Two columns. One becomes the index of the pandas dataframe, the other is the data.

Comment: @Escachator, actually i think, your approach is already the most memory-saving, compared to reading ALL CSVs into memory and concatenating them. I would simply make use of `chunksize` parameter - reading all CSVs in chunks - this might save you some RAM

Comment: @MaxU You are right, that intuitively seems that you save more memory. But I am running jezrael solution and so far has not crashed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')

dfs = [pd.read_csv(file_name,index_col=0,header=None).dropna() for file_name in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs).sum()
print (df)
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying it, will report. Why would this be more "memory efficient"?

Comment: Good question, I am not 100% sure if it will be more memmory efficient, because if use huge files, it can be problematic. But the best its test it.

Comment: I think concat and sum won't work, as I want to sum rows with same index for each element of dfs. I guess we need to transform the problem to sum over repeated indices, once the concat is done...

Comment: So do you need groupby by duplicated index in each file and sum? If yes, use  `dfs = [pd.read_csv(file_name,index_col=0,header=None).dropna().groupby(level=0).sum() for file_name in files]` ?

Comment: Another solution, if need groupby in concated `df`, then use `df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).sum()`.

Comment: Thank you, the last version: pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).sum() worked well. Do you mind to edit your answer with that so that it remains documented?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** i would simply add reading all CSVs in chunks to your solution. I think you are already doing it very well in terms of memory saving...

```
sum_of_all_files = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in list_of_files:
    for file_df in pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col=0, header=None, chunksize=10**5)
        sum_of_all_files = sum_of_all_files.add(file_df.dropna(), fill_value=0,  axis='index')
```

**OLD answer:**

**Idea:** we will read first file into `total` DF and then we will read one file in each iteration step starting from the second file in your `list_of_files` and add it on the fly to the `total` DF

PS you can go further and read each CSV files in chunks if there are huge files that don't fit into memory:

```
total = pd.read_csv(list_of_files[0], index_col=0, header=None).dropna()

for f in list_of_files[1:]:
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(f,index_col=0,header=None, chunksize=10**5):
        total = total.add(chunk.dropna(), fill_value=0, axis='index')
```

Comment: thanks! Will try that. If I don't use dropna the number of rows will "explode", as in each file there are millions of empty rows. The data is not aligned, I need to add them by index. And I believe there is another error in my code...

Comment: @Escachator, sure, give it a try